# Программа для создания flash изображений.

Tags: flash

Хочу на сайт добавить монету, типа [такой](http://mmcis.ua/), чтобы тоже крутилась. Какой программой это можно сделать? Какая проще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Отрендерить монетку в 3д пакете, видео последовательность закодить в *.FLV (Adobe Media Encoder), на сайте разместить любой бесплатный/свой видеоплеер на флеше (самый визуально продвинутый вариант).

   1. Видеопоследовательность импортировать в Flash Pro (СS), он сам соберет флешку с анимацией.
   2. Видеопоследовательность импортировать в Adobe AfterEffect (CS), результат экспортировать в SWF или GIF format.
2. Покадрово собрать векторную анимацию во Flash Pro (CS).
3. Самый правильный и кастомизируемый - сделать простую модельку монеты (плоский цилиндр с текстурами сторон и ребер), собрать флешку на каком нить ActionScript3 3д движке (alternativa3d, away3d, papervision3d), которая будет крутить модельку

Comment: Сложно, но мне надо программа для создания

Answer (score 0):

Может уже старо, но вообще через Macromedia Flash Professional. Вот  похожий пример, хорошая книга Б.Г.Жадаева 100% Самоучитель Flash MX.